# SQL Server query + ASP.NET: Counting unique user's post(s) and then making a link to open those posts in a gridview

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio

I was just going through in the making of a project. I am using SQL Server 2008 Expresss, ASP.NET (VB backend), .NET Framework 3.5

My question is related to :

I have a table with columns such as `: userid, postid, postname, postval` etc.

Now what I would like to do is to present a list of unique user's post counts.

As well as a simple navigation facility such as: a link from those unique post counts by a user. Suppose "abc" is the user.. on clicking the no. of counts of posts by abc (in a list of others) I will be redirected to another list having a gridview or any suitable tabular format for viewing those particular posts by "abc" user.

How can I achieve this..? My mind is all but confused over the query / implementation part :X

Cheers,
-[echo9]-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> now what I would like to do is to
>   present a list of unique user's post
>   counts

```
SELECT 
    userid
    ,count(postid) as post_count
FROM
    the_table
Group By
    userid
```

Now you can bind this to a datagrid (or even better a datarepeater) with an item template that looks like:

```
 <ItemTemplate>
    <div>
          <a href="myShowListPage.aspx?userid='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, 
          "userid") %>' <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "userid") %>
    </div>
    <div>
          <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, 
          "post_count") %>' </div>
  </ItemTemplate>
```

Now you will have to use styles and css classes to get the layout and effect you want, but this will move you in the right direction.

*note: another suggestion that you learn entity framework is valuable, but may not get you moving very quickly*

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use Entity Framework ..

[Read about it](http://www.asp.net/entity-framework/tutorials)

Comment: That statement is a little out...  There are *many* ORMs available, you shouldn't make the OP feel they have no choice but to learn EF.  I would down vote but I'm not cool enough...